# USB headset won't work on newer computer with the same OS

Tags: windows-8, usb, drivers, usb-headset, windows-8-x64

I have an inexpensive USB headset Somic G927. And I didn't have any problems using in my older computer Lenovo 3000 n200 (yes, it's a laptop from 2008 which is still working).

Now, I bought a Clevo P177SM and Windows won't recognize this device at all.
Tried both driver packages available at the Somic's website:

[Digital virtual 7.1 sound effect gaming headset driver (For Win8)](http://www.somic-elec.com/img/down/Digital%20virtual%207.1%20sound%20effect%20gaming%20headset%20driver%20%28For%20Win8%29.rar)

[Digital virtual 7.1 sound effect gaming headset driver](http://www.somic-elec.com/img/down/Digital%20virtual%207.1%20sound%20effect%20gaming%20headset%20driver.rar)

Despite of the names in both there are Windows 8 drivers.

I am using Windows 8.1 x64 on both computers and even tried to copy the driver from one to the other using **DriverMax**.

> Additional info from *Device Manager* > Unknown USB Device (Invalid Device Descriptor) Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43) -

*Note> I didn't even had to actually install the USB Headset driver on the older computer.*

**The question: Is this everything I can do (and then give up) or there is another way to install such driver?**

EDIT: Driver installation error (forgot to mention this) -> When I try to install the USB driver the setup display a diagbox saying that I have to insert the Device (tried in all USB ports and puting before/during the setup) still the same error. Note the device is still working on the lenovo.

I hope that there is enough information above, but I can always provide more (just request for it in the comments)

Is this question clear? ( I would really appreciate **any** feedback on this question because I still don't wanna give up on this problem)